# Accessing docker-cli string array element in Go templates

Tags: go-templates, docker-cli

I created a docker container but cannot seem to parse its properties with docker-cli and its `format` parameter (which uses *Go templates*).

Any idea greatly appreciated.

1. Start a docker container, e.g. go to https://birthday.play-with-docker.com/cli-formating/ and click on the docker command in the *Prepare the environment* section
2. Choose a property for parsing, e.g. *Ports*. Printing it with `docker container ls --format '{{ .Ports }}'` should yield `0.0.0.0:80->80/tcp`.
3. Trying to get the port range part after the colon, split the property at ":" (`docker container ls --format '{{ split .Ports ":" }}'`) which yields array `[0.0.0.0 80->80/tcp]`
4. The return type (`docker container ls --format '{{ printf "%T" (split .Ports ":") }}'`) is
   `[]string`.
5. The string array has a length of 2 (`docker container ls --format '{{ len (split .Ports ":") }}'`) .
6. Accessing index value 0 (`docker container ls --format '{{ index (split .Ports ":") 0 }}'`) yields `0.0.0.0` as expected.
7. Accessing index value 1 (`docker container ls --format '{{ index (split .Ports ":") 1 }}'`)  yields *failed to execute template: template: :1:2: executing "" at <index (split .Ports ":") 1>: error calling index: reflect: slice index out of range* instead of `80->80/tcp` .

Comment: There doesn't seem to be a single line of Go code on your question. Is it maybe more specific to docker than to the Go language itself?

Comment: Might seem so but docker-cli indeed uses _Go templates_ for the `format` parameter. See [Format command and log output](https://docs.docker.com/config/formatting/).

Answer (score 0):

In order to access string array elements, I found a solution.
As this question focuses on the Go templates part in the `--format` parameter, I will just write about that.

The `{{ index (split .Ports ":") 1 }}` yields an error because `index` simply is the wrong function in this case. To access an array element, use `slice`:

1. Access the second array element (zero-based index) with `{{ slice (split .Ports ":") 1 }}`, this yields `[80->80/tcp]`.
2. If you need `string` output, you can convert the `slice` object with `join` using `""` as separator, removing the square brackets in the output: `{{ join ( slice (split .Image ":") 1 ) "" }}` yields `80->80/tcp`.

The complete command is `docker container ls --format '{{ join ( slice ( split .Ports ":" ) 1 ) "" }}'`. Keep in mind that *Go templates* use a kind of prefix notation which might not seem that common.